# How to limit the amount of records associated to a object without limiting the process of storing new records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, record

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 and I would like to limit the amount of database records associated to a object *without* limiting the process of storing new records. That is, I have a `Article` class that `has_many :reviews` and I would like to store at maximum 10 reviews per article and overwrite the oldest review when a new one more than ten is submitted. For example, given 10 reviews have been submitted for an article when a new review is submitted for that article then I would like to retrieve the oldest review and overwrite that (without create a new review in the database).

I thought to make that in the `Review` model by overwriting, when 10 review are present in the database for a given article, the `created_at` attribute in addition to all other attributes. In other words, I want to avoid to create a new record (with a new `id`) but update the oldest one with the new data just submitted so to store the 10 *most recent* reviews. It seems to work as-like a FIFO queue.

How can / should I make that?

---

*Note*: The solution proposed by @bgates may be good, but I would like to avoid destroying oldest and then creating new (or viceversa) records because, by adopting the @bgates' solution, record `ids` will grow significantly over the time (eg: 1, 2, ..., 34, ..., 7897987987, ...) since *new reviews are submitted constantly*, approximately each 20 seconds. Should I worry about the growth of `ids`?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an advantage at the database layer to doing it that way? At the Rails level it would be easier to add an `after_save` hook to the `Review` model-

```
def purge_old_reviews
  while article.reviews.count > 10
    article.reviews.first.destroy
  end
end
```

(assuming article.reviews are sorted oldest-first)

Comment: I would like to avoid destroying oldest and then creating new (or viceversa) records. I think so because I would like to keep using the same references (`ids`) to records present in the database and because record `ids` will grow significantly (eg: 1, 2, ..., 34, ..., 7897987987, ...) since *new reviews are submitted constantly*, approximately each 10 seconds. Should I worry about the growth of `ids`?

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem, and by the time you get that many reviews you will be able to hire 10 fulltime DBAs to worry about it for you. :)

Comment: What do you mean with "you will be able to hire 10 fulltime DBAs"? What is a DBA?

Comment: DataBase Administrators - if you have hundreds of millions of reviews, you will make enough money on the site to hire someone to tell you whether it's a problem. I'm fairly positive it isn't, and even if you were adding a new review every second it would still take you over 3 years to get to 100 million reviews. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I have right reasons to think that it's a problem (articles and reviews mentioned in the question are just sample objects - I can not say what's on right here). Even more since your words, I need to update existing records and not delete and create those as you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to update the oldest article, you could use the `updated_at` attribute.

that is,

```
def write_new_review
    reviews = article.reviews
    if reviews.length > 10
        oldest_review = reviews.limit(1).order('updated_at ASC')
        oldest_review.update_attributes({your: updates})
    else
        # add new review
    end
end
```

then call it when you want to create a new article

Comment: If you use that code in a callback then the review that is going to be saved should not be saved. Just the oldest review should be updated. Maybe I have to handle my issue in the related controller `create` action instead of the model.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I didn't read the answer close enough (I've updated my answer).  You wouldn't want to use that method in a callback.  You'd want to do something like `article.write_new_review`.  That method would take a slightly different definition.  But, the issue of updating the oldest review would be solved the same way